Add suffixe in citation labels
In a project, I have to concatenate multiple bibliographies.
In order to avoid duplicates, I add a suffix to every labels and a userf field.
But to keep the insertion of reference simple, is it possible to tweak the cite command in order to automatically add the suffix?
In the MWE below, is it possible to use \cite{ref1,ref2}, meaning \cite{ref1_A,ref2_A}?
In the use case, the suffix is kept within a whole document.
% !TeX document-id = {a3ebeb0c-3089-4bb9-a0a6-8f32c835bc23}
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR

% !TeX program = lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}{Txs.bib}
  @book{ref1_A,
    userf = {A},
    title="Title 1",
    author="Name1,Surname1",
    year="2011",
  }
  @book{ref1_B,
    userf = {B},
    title="Title 1",
    author="Name1,Surname1",
    year="2011",
  }
  @book{ref2_A,
    userf = {A},
    title="Title 2",
    author="Name2,Surname2",
    year="2011",
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\def\code{A} % suffix to use in the citations

\let\oldcite\cite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{O{}O{}m}{
  \seq_clear_new:N \l_tmp_cite_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmp_cite_seq {,} {#3}
  \oldcite[#1][#2]{\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmp_cite_seq { ##1_\code, }}
}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Txs.bib}
\defbibcheck{A}{\iffieldequalstr{userf}{A}{}{\skipentry}}


\begin{document}
  \cite{ref1,ref2}

  \printbibliography[check=\Code]
  
\end{document}


I'm not sure about your aim. Are you intending to select specific entries and create a separate bibliography exclusively for them?

@FrancescoContini, I have a huge bib file in which each entry has a suffix (and a userf field). For some documents I need to print the bibliography filtering on the userf value but using the original label (without the suffix) when calling the \cite command. Thus, I've to tweak the command to automatically add the suffix in the label.

Based on this answer of quite similar question, I added the following lines in the preamble:
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\blx@citeadd#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}
  {\letcs\blx@realkey{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}}
  {\def\blx@realkey{#1 \c_underscore_str \Code}}%
  \expandafter\blx@getrefcontext\expandafter{\blx@realkey}% needed for \ifdata
  \expandafter\blx@citation\expandafter{\blx@realkey}\blx@msg@cundefon
  \expandafter\blx@ifdata\expandafter{\blx@realkey}
  {\advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne
    \listeadd\blx@tempa{\blx@realkey}}
  {\ifnum\blx@tempcntb>\z@\multicitedelim\fi
    \expandafter\abx@missing@entry\expandafter{\blx@realkey}%
    \advance\blx@tempcntb\@ne}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

